# dynamic master template in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, master-pages

My problem is this:

I have a masterpage:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo isset($title)? $title: NULL; ?></title>
    <?php $this->load->view('layout/header'); ?>
</head>
<body>           
     <!-- BEGIN PAGE BASE CONTENT -->
         <?php $this->load->view($content);?>
     <!-- END PAGE BASE CONTENT -->       
</body>
```

and my dashboard controller:

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
      if($this->session->userdata('login') == true){
        $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
        $data['content'] = 'pages/dashboard';
        $this->load->view('layout/master', $data);
    }
    else{
        redirect('auth');
    }
    }
```

and my add controller:

```
if($this->session->userdata('login') == true){
    $data['title'] = 'افزودن مشتری';
    $data['content'] = 'pages/add_customer';
    $this->load->view('layout/master', $data);
}
else{
    redirect('auth');
}
```

My problem is that at first when i call dashboard, everything is OK. but when i call add, everything mess up like there is no CSS attached or something.
Should i do something before set value to $content? 
I cant understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, where is your `if($condition)`? Then the `auth` controller waht it makes?

Comment: @elddenmedio
You are right. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When in a function you can't do anything with it. But can't do anything outside. Like your else statement.

```
public function add(){
    $data['title'] = 'افزودن مشتری';
    $data['content'] = 'pages/add_customer';
    $this->load->view('layout/master', $data);
}
else{
    redirect('auth');
}
```

**This is completely wrong practices**. Just use

```
public function add(){
    $data['title'] = 'افزودن مشتری';
    $data['content'] = 'pages/add_customer';
    $this->load->view('layout/master', $data);
}
```

---

**Load Codeigniter for the Arabic Letters**

Codeigniter by default is set to use UTF-8 for much of its internal functionality, so just make sure the charset is set to UTF-8 in your `application/config/config.php` file.

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

**And set the header too**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.
I've just forgot to place the if statement:
if($this->session->userdata('login') == true)
Edited my question. See that please :)

Comment: @user1767712 did you set UTF and header to that??

Comment: Yes. Set that in the master page.

Comment: @user1767712 happy to help :)